# Affecting only parent LI

Tags: jquery, css

Im making a menu with a sub menu with a changing `line-height`

however I cannot stop this line-height from effecting my child (sub menu) li,

I have tried `ul.nav > li` but it still effects the lower menu bar..

```
$(window).on("scroll resize load", function () {
    if($(window).width() > 863) {
        wide();

        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 75) headerLow();
        else headerHigh();
    } else {
        headerLow();
        thin();
    }
});

var headerHigh = function () {
    $('#head').removeClass('mini').css('height', '75' );
};

var headerLow = function () {
    $('#head').addClass('mini').css('height', '60' );
};

var thin = function() {
    $('#slider').css({ 'padding-top' : '60px'});
};

var wide = function() {
    $('#slider').css( 'padding-top' , '78px');
};
```

---

```
<div id="head">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
            <li><a href="#"></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.nav li { line-height: 80px;transition: line-height 0.5s ease; }  
.nav li > ul li { line-height: 10px; }
.mini ul.nav > li, .mini .logo { line-height: 60px; }
.mini h1 { font-size: 2em; }
```

The problem is when i scroll down, the second menu is affected by .mini.  [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5pjm9n3h/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `li:nth-child(3) { line-height: 60px; }`

**NOTE:** This will affect the inner li's not the sub li's.

Read [this](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) to understand How nth-child Works.

or

Give your li's a **class** and apply CSS using that class.

```
<ul>
    <li class="menuLI">Menu</li>
    <li class="menuLI">About Us</li>
    <li class="menuLI">Contact Us
        <ul>
            <li class="subMenuLI">Starters</li>
            <li class="subMenuLI">Breakfast and Brunch</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the updated [**`JSFiddle Link`**](http://jsfiddle.net/Varun_Chakervarti/5pjm9n3h/9/)

**Note:** Here is what I have updated.

```
.nav li > ul li{ line-height: 40px; } // Updated
.nav li ul { line-height: 0px; } // Added
```

Comment: okay, so i have used your second approach with multiple variations, not of wich work with out moving the child LI. I'm not sure I understand the first one.

Comment: I have added JSFiddle link and updated it, Check it out. Also added the updation.

Answer (score 0):

Using the selector `ul.nav > li` is correct. That selector is referring to elements you would expect it to refer to, as demonstrated by this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gavgk5vs/).

I think the problem is due to inheritance. No matter what elements you select, [the child `li` elements will inherit the `line-height` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height). To get around this problem, you would just respecify a more appropriate `line-height` value that does not affect your design.

I hope this answers your question!